# Iterate through JS object/array, and if you find a match change the value and return the original object/array structure

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to get a functionality like PHP in Javascript/Jquery, where we pass the address of a value (&$value) and edit its value in the actual array structure in PHP. For example I have a object in the following format,

```
var obj = {
    "first": "first value",
    "second": "second value",
    "third": "third value",
    "fourth": {
        "a": "good word",
        "b": "bad word"
    }
}
```

Array/Object can be single or multidimensional. And I want to iterate through the given array/object structure and modify it and return the actual structure back.

```
var obj = {
    "first": "modified value",
    "second": "second value",
    "third": "third value",
    "fourth": {
        "a": "good word",
        "b": "censored word"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recursively applies a function to a nested object:

```
transform = function(obj, fun) {
    if (typeof obj != "object")
        return fun(obj);
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
        obj[k] = transform(obj[k], fun);
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
transform(yourData, function(val) {
    if (val.replace)
        return val.replace(/bad/g, "censored");
    else
        return val;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through a JS object with a [for in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Here's an example from the docs:

```
var o = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

function show_props(obj, objName) {
  var result = "";

  for (var prop in obj) {
    result += objName + "." + prop + " = " + obj[prop] + "\n";
  }

  return result;
}

alert(show_props(o, "o")); /* alerts: o.a = 1 o.b = 2 o.c = 3 */
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works only on objects (`{}`), let me know if you actually need to include arrays (`[]`) :

```
function searchAndDestroy(o, word, replacement) {
    var value, type;
    for (var k in o) {
        value = o[k];
        type = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);
        if (type === '[object Object]') {
            searchAndDestroy(value, word, replacement);
        } else if (type === '[object String]') {
            o[k] = value.replace(new RegExp(word, 'g'), replacement);
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

Usage :

```
var sanitized = searchAndDestroy(obj, 'bad word', 'censored word');
```

What you need to know :

- PHP indexed arrays can be translated into Javascript arrays (`[]`).
- PHP associative arrays can be translated into Javascript objects (`{}`).
- Finally, Javascript composite data types, objects (`{}`) and arrays (`[]`), are always passed by reference and there is no way to change that. Consequently, regarding the use case above, `sanitized` equals `obj`.